# Oracle Proxy User and Client Connection Pooling

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, proxy, odp.net

With an internal web app, we decided to use Oracle's Proxy Authentication in order to get the benefits of connection pooling, but still get the actual user passed to the database. Main use of this is for triggers to pick up the username and insert for a Modified By field.

Tested it initially and all seemed fine. Now we are testing with multiple users and are having problems. Whoever gets in first seems to be the only user that is captured at the database (at least for a while). I suspect that it is due to the client connection pooling, where the first person gets a connection and then disconnects. Next person hits web server and ODP.Net gives that person the other connection. I can only assume it doesn't change out the user properly.

Is this intended behavior or perhaps a problem with the client?

We are using 64-bit 11g (11.2.0.4.0) with ODP.Net of 4.112.3.0 and are only using the client's connection pooling; we are NOT using Database Resident Connection Pooling (DRCP).

Our connection string:
Data Source=myOracleDB; Proxy User Id=pUserId;Proxy Password=pPassword; User Id=myUsername;

Comment: That's a very old version of ODP.NET (at least 4 years). Can you give this a try with the latest 12.1 version of ODP.NET and let us know? There's been tons of bug fixes since then. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Comment: Upgrading the ODP.Net does not help. I upgraded to 4.121.2.0 Release 4, but got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. I failed to mention that we are using an ORM, NHibernate. That is what is causing the problem. The Connection String gets set as part of the setup of NHibernate's Session Factory, which should be set up as a one-time setup object. This causes all NHibernate Sessions to be created with the same connection string (and username). This will persist for the lifetime of the Session Factory.

The solution is to override NHibernate's DriverConnectionProvider class and override the ConnectionString property to set the ConnectionString to include your current user. Then specify the following in your web.config:
`<property name="connection.provider">MyConnectionProvider, MyAssembly</property>`